# remove css expression from Facebook social plugin

Tags: css, facebook, expression

how can I remove css expression from Facebook social plugin (like box)?

Answer (score 0):

[From Facebook policy](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/) :

> **IV. Application Integration Points**
>
> 6 d. You must not obscure or cover elements of our social plugins,
>   such as the Like button or Like box
>   plugin.

Meaning that you should not change or remove styling of the like button styling, unless you want to have problems with FB.

Answer (score 0):

Use the iframe option when you choose to get the code. That fixed it for me... I know it's lame but it's the only way to pass the Yslow checkup on CSS expressions.

Stupid facebook still supporting IE6 ....